# cannot use values from beans in facelets custom component

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

i cannot use any bean value in my custom control.:
for instance:

this is my foo.taglib.xml file.

```
<facelet-taglib>
  <namespace>http://www.penguenyuvasi.org/tags</namespace>
  <tag>
    <tag-name>test</tag-name>
    <component>
      <component-type>test.Data</component-type>
    </component>
  </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

faces-config.xml

```
  <component>
    <component-type>test.Data</component-type>
    <component-class>test.Data</component-class>
  </component>
```

test.Data class

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class Data extends UIComponentBase {

  private Object msg;

  @Override
  public String getFamily() {
    return "test.Data";
  }

  @Override
  public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    super.encodeBegin(context);
    context.getResponseWriter().write(msg.toString());
  }

  public void setMsg(Object msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
  }
}
```

Bean.java:

```
package test;

public class Bean {

  private String temp = "vada";

  public String getTemp() {
    return temp;
  }
}
```

test.xhtml (doesn't work)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://www.penguenyuvasi.org/tags">
    <py:test msg="#{bean.temp}" />
</html>
```

test.xhtml (works)

```
    <py:test msg="#{bean.temp}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test.Data class, I suggest that you implement the getter for `msg` like that:

```
public String getMsg() {
    if (msg != null) {
        return msg;
    }
    ValueBinding vb = getValueBinding("msg");
    if (vb != null) {
        return (String) vb.getValue(getFacesContext());
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then, in your `encodeBegin` method:

```
...
context.getResponseWriter().write(getMsg());
...
```

This getter method is needed in order to evaluate the expression you may give to the `msg` attribute in your JSF page.

Edit, to use ValueExpression instead of the deprecated ValueBinding:

```
ValueExpression ve = getValueExpression("msg");
if (ve != null) {
    return (String) ve.getValue(getFacesContext().getELContext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Excellent solution.
Additional info: ValueBinding is deprecated. ValueExpression should be used.

Comment: Yes, indeed, ValueExpression must be used instead.

Comment: ValueExpression ve = getValueExpression("msg");

         if (ve != null) {
           return (String) ve.getValue(getFacesContext().getELContext());
         }